# How to implement RGB gradient from top to bottom in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

If two UIColors are

```
UIColor *colr1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.553 blue:0.416 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *colr2 =[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.341 blue:0.263 alpha:1.0];
```

How to make view's(myView with frame CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)) background color  gradient of these two color from top to bottom.
 Kindly give some code for this(iOS7).Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = yourView.bounds;
UIColor *colr1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.553 blue:0.416 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *colr2 =[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.341 blue:0.263 alpha:1.0];
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[colr1 CGColor], (id)[colr2 CGColor], nil];
[yourView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```